# getDownloadUrl function doesn't return the right url

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am uploading a pdf to Firebase Storage and want to get its download url. I am using the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1212:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String FilePath = data.getDataString();
                t.setText(FilePath);
                Uri pdfuri = data.getData();
                final StorageReference mp = mpdf.child("pdf").child(random()+".pdf");
                mp.putFile(pdfuri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            String download_url = task.getResult().getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                            String parent = getIntent().getStringExtra("type").toString();
                            String ch = getIntent().getStringExtra("value").toString();
                            GeologicDatabase.modifySingle(parent,ch,download_url);
                            Toast.makeText(modifypdf.this,download_url , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            finish();
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(modifypdf.this,"Faild" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

the result of the line

```
String download_url = task.getResult().getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString();
```

is 
"com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@7f93358"
not the right url

---

the solution of the problem is to use upload task and in its in Complete Listener you write your code get the result of the task as a Uri and cast it into String

```
final String name = random() + ".pdf";
                dp = mpdf.child("pdf").child(name);
                UploadTask uploadTask = dp.putFile(pdfuri);
                Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            throw task.getException();
                        }

                        // Continue with the task to get the download URL
                        return dp.getDownloadUrl();
                    }
                }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            tt = title.getText().toString();
                            Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                            String download_url = downloadUri.toString();
                            String parent = getIntent().getStringExtra("type").toString();
                            String ch = getIntent().getStringExtra("value").toString();
                            GeologicDatabase.updateChild(parent, ch, "url",download_url,tt);
                            GeologicDatabase.updateChild(parent,ch,"name",name,tt);
                            Toast.makeText(addpdf.this, download_url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            // Handle failures
                            // ...
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[getDownloadUrl()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#getDownloadUrl()) doesn't return a URL.  As you can see from [the javadoc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#getDownloadUrl()), it returns a Task that yields the URL.  You'll have to wait on this Task to complete in order to get the final URL.

Comment: according to your answer i think i should override onComplete method
but what to write inside to get the download url

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service.  Please consult the documentation and give it a try for yourself.  Then if you're still stuck, ask another question describing the problem and what you've tried so far.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url

Comment: thanks but it's really not about code writing i tried but it's not working , i searched and i couldn't find it, i implemented but i am a beginner , documentation is not enough to me , it is a so simple solution to have a sample of code  that can be customized to get my target
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u4uC4LBOb_bDS3Zq_tWyiMze4s4Iidbh/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

//Try this one

```
Task<Uri> newTask = task.getResult().getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl();
            newTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    yourUriVariable= uri;
                }
            });
```